# Linking Two Form Inputs to Update Dynamically in relation to each other

Tags: javascript, css, html

*Just Learning Javascript so please be kind*

Background: Bootstrap based site with contact form and I wanted to use the html5 `input type="range"` element. Found a prettified version using modernizr on codepen ([original here](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/PwxKjm)) and basically just updated the CSS styling to my requirements.

I need the slider to 'update' in relation to a dropdown menu and wrote a basic javascript function that achieves this (kinda).. see code below.

Problem: The 'original' slider functionality (updates the 'tooltip' style value on drag) still exists. With my own javascript function I can change the range value using the dropdown BUT does not update the -ms-fill-lower or the tooltip value.

The original javascript is a bit beyond my current abilities; I'm not really sure what value I should be trying to update with my own function etc. I think it may be something to do with input element focus but if someone could please point me in the right direction as to how I target/link the correct value/element to create the desired results so that the range slider 'updates correctly' when selecting the desired value from the drop down menu I would be very grateful!

```js
//ORIGINAL SLIDER JAVASCRIPT

var range_el = document.querySelector('input[type=range]'),
  style_el = document.createElement('style'),
  range_style = getComputedStyle(range_el),
  pad = range_style.paddingTop.split('px')[0],
  w = range_style.width.split('px')[0],
  fill_max_w = w - 2 * pad,
  messages = [
    'Making an enquiry',
    'Not sure its for me',
    'Want to know more',
    'Very interested',
    'I want to do this',
    'Ready to Start',
  ];

document.body.appendChild(style_el);

range_el.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var perc = this.value,
    dec = perc / 100,
    fill_w = Math.round(dec * fill_max_w),
    msg = messages[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (perc > i * 25 && i <= (i + 1) * 25) {
      msg = messages[(perc == 100) ? 5 : ((perc == 50) ? 6 : (i + 1))];
    }
  }

  style_el.textContent =
    '.js input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track:before,' +
    '.js input[type=range] /deep/ #track:before{width:' + fill_w + 'px}' +
    '.js input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before,' +
    '.js input[type=range] /deep/ #thumb:before{content:"' + perc + '%"}' +
    '.js input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:after,' +
    '.js input[type=range] /deep/ #thumb:after{content:"' + msg + '"}';
}, false);

//MY JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION

function changeValueMobile() {
  var option = document.getElementById('commitmentmobile').value;

  if (option == "Ready to Start") {
    document.getElementById('commitmentdesktop').value = 100;
  } else if (option == "I want to do this") {
    document.getElementById('commitmentdesktop').value = 80;
  } else if (option == "Very interested") {
    document.getElementById('commitmentdesktop').value = 60;
  } else if (option == "I want to know more") {
    document.getElementById('commitmentdesktop').value = 40;
  } else if (option == "Not sure this is right for me") {
    document.getElementById('commitmentdesktop').value = 20;
  } else if (option == "Just making an enquiry") {
    document.getElementById('commitmentdesktop').value = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
/*CSS STYLES */
input[type='range'] {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 20px auto;
  padding: 0.75em 0 0.25em 0;
  max-width: 28em;
  width: 90%;
  height: 3em;
  opacity: .75;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #def3f8, inset 0 .125em .125em #0d1112;
  background: #ccc;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.25em;
  width: 28em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #def3f8, inset 0 .125em .125em #0d1112;
  background: #ccc;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-track {
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.25em;
  width: 28em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #def3f8, inset 0 .125em .125em #0d1112;
  background: #ccc;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-progress {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: solid 0.25em transparent;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em 0.1875em 0.1875em 0.5em / 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #09313d, inset 0 1px 1px #c0edf3;
  background: #e12726;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 0.75em 0.1875em 0.1875em 0.75em / 50%;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower {
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em 0.1875em 0.1875em 0.5em / 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #09313d, inset 0 1px 1px #c0edf3;
  background: #e12726;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -0.375em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 0.125em rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
  width: 2.25em;
  height: 2.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 .125em .125em #3b4547;
  background: $brandbasic;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% .125em, .125em 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 115% 115%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px #516570);
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 0.125em rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
  width: 2.25em;
  height: 2.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 .125em .125em #3b4547;
  background: radial-gradient(#777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 70%) 50% 50%, radial-gradient(#777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 70%) 50% 50%, radial-gradient(at 50% 0 at 50% 0, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 50% 0, radial-gradient(at 50% 100% at 50% 100%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 50% 100%, radial-gradient(at 0 50% at 0 50%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 0 50%, radial-gradient(at 100% 50% at 100% 50%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 100% 50%, radial-gradient(rgba(59, 69, 71, 0) 50%, #3b4547 71%) 50% -0.25em #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% .125em, .125em 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 115% 115%;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 0.125em rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
  width: 2.25em;
  height: 2.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 .125em .125em #3b4547;
  background: radial-gradient(#777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 70%) 50% 50%, radial-gradient(#777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 70%) 50% 50%, radial-gradient(at 50% 0 at 50% 0, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 50% 0, radial-gradient(at 50% 100% at 50% 100%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 50% 100%, radial-gradient(at 0 50% at 0 50%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 0 50%, radial-gradient(at 100% 50% at 100% 50%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 100% 50%, radial-gradient(rgba(59, 69, 71, 0) 50%, #3b4547 71%) 50% -0.25em #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% .125em, .125em 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 115% 115%;
}
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track:before,
.js input[type='range'] /deep/ #track:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25em;
  left: 0.25em;
  width: 0em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em 0.1875em 0.1875em 0.5em / 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #09313d, inset 0 1px 1px #c0edf3;
  background: #e12726;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  content: '';
}
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:before,
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:after,
.js input[type='range'] /deep/ #thumb:before,
.js input[type='range'] /deep/ #thumb:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  color: #ebeef3;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(211, 23, 22, 0.5);
}
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:before,
.js input[type='range'] /deep/ #thumb:before {
  width: 4em;
  height: 2.25em;
  border-radius: 0.125em;
  transform: translate(-50%, -0.5em);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #d1e4f9;
  background: #212121;
  clip-path: polygon(2.375em 1.875em, 2em 2.25em, 1.625em 1.875em, 0.125em 1.875em, 0.07716em 1.86548em, 0.03661em 1.83839em, 0.00952em 1.79784em, 0em 1.75em, 0em 0.125em, 0.00952em 0.07716em, 0.03661em 0.03661em, 0.07716em 0.00952em, 0.125em 0em, 3.875em 0em, 3.92284em 0.00952em, 3.96339em 0.03661em, 3.99048em 0.07716em, 4em 0.125em, 4em 1.75em, 3.99048em 1.79784em, 3.96339em 1.83839em, 3.92284em 1.86548em, 3.875em 1.875em);
  font: 2em/1.40625em trebuchet ms, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  content: "0%";
}
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:after,
.js input[type='range'] /deep/ #thumb:after {
  width: 9.6em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -2.75em);
  box-shadow: 0 2.25em 0.625em -0.5em rgba(55, 84, 92, 0.75);
  font: 0.75em trebuchet ms, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  content: "Making an enquiry";
}
input[type='range']:focus {
  outline: none;
  opacity: .99;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <input type='range' id="commitmentdesktop" class="form-control" name="commitmentdesktop" value='0' step="20">
    <select id="commitmentmobile" name="commitmentmobile" class="form-control smaller-select" onchange="changeValueMobile();">
      <option>&nbsp;</option>
      <option value="Ready to Start">I'm ready to Start</option>
      <option value="I want to do this">I want to do this</option>
      <option value="Very interested">I'm very interested</option>
      <option value="I want to know more">I want to know more</option>
      <option value="Not sure this is right for me">I'm not sure this is right for me</option>
      <option value="Just making an enquiry">Just making an enquiry</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-md-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Why are your options' values strings? Shouldn't they be indices (IDs)? Also, you should use a switch-statement rather than a bunch of if-elses inside `changeValueMobile()`.

Comment: I couldn't get the form to post correctly when I used ID's. Couldn't remedy that immediately though it is something I was aware of. I would love to use a switch-statement had I any idea what that was.. I'll look into it. Really a beginner here. If you can guide a little beyond that in the right direction for my mentioned problem it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the following changes:

- Added a reference to your `<SELECT>` element.
- Created a data array for the select `<OPTIONS>`s.
- Populated the `<SELECT>` box using JavaScript.
- Added the style element to the `<HEAD>`. (Only for convention)
- For consistency, removed the `onchange` from your select element.
- Fixed the scale logic to convert the selected index to an percentage.

### Code

Here is a link to an [external JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn7zm9e0/5/) (same code as below), but you can run it right here on this page.

```js
// Reference elements.
var range_el = document.querySelector('input[type=range]'),
    select_el = document.querySelector('select[name=commitmentmobile]'),
    style_el = document.createElement('style');

// Other variables.
var range_style = getComputedStyle(range_el),
    pad = range_style.paddingTop.split('px')[0],
    w = range_style.width.split('px')[0],
    fill_max_w = w - 2 * pad,
    options = [
        { val : 0,   msg : 'Making an enquiry',   text : "Just making an enquiry" },
        { val : 20,  msg : 'Not sure its for me', text : "I'm not sure this is right for me" },
        { val : 40,  msg : 'Want to know more',   text : "I want to know more" },
        { val : 60,  msg : 'Very interested',     text : "I'm very interested" },
        { val : 80,  msg : 'I want to do this',   text : "I want to do this" },
        { val : 100, msg : 'Ready to Start',      text : "I'm ready to Start" }
    ];

// Populate select box.
for (var i = options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var option_el = document.createElement('option');
    option_el.value = i;
    option_el.innerHTML = options[i].text;
    select_el.appendChild(option_el);
}

// Add style element to the head.
document.head.appendChild(style_el);

// Event listeners.
range_el.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    updateSlider();
}, false);

select_el.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var option = Number(select_el.value);
    range_el.value = options[option].val;
    updateSlider();
});

// Update function which binds the range slider to the select box.
function updateSlider() {
    var perc = range_el.value,
        step = range_el.step,
        index = Math.floor(perc / step),
        msg = options[index].msg,
        scale = (perc - 1) / 100,
        fill_w = Math.round(scale * fill_max_w);

    style_el.textContent = [
        '.js input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track:before,',
        '.js input[type=range] /deep/ #track:before{width:' + fill_w + 'px}',
        '.js input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before,',
        '.js input[type=range] /deep/ #thumb:before{content:"' + perc + '%"}',
        '.js input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:after,',
        '.js input[type=range] /deep/ #thumb:after{content:"' + msg + '"}',
    ].join(' ');
    
    select_el.value = index;
}
```

```css
input[type='range'] {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto 20px auto;
    padding: 0.75em 0 0.25em 0;
    max-width: 28em;
    width: 90%;
    height: 3em;
    opacity: .75;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='range'], input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 0.75em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #def3f8, inset 0 .125em .125em #0d1112;
    background: #ccc;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0.25em;
    width: 28em;
    height: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 0.75em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #def3f8, inset 0 .125em .125em #0d1112;
    background: #ccc;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-track {
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0.25em;
    width: 28em;
    height: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 0.75em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #def3f8, inset 0 .125em .125em #0d1112;
    background: #ccc;
    color: transparent;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-progress {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: solid 0.25em transparent;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0.1875em 0.1875em 0.5em / 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #09313d, inset 0 1px 1px #c0edf3;
    background: #e12726;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 0.75em 0.1875em 0.1875em 0.75em / 50%;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-fill-lower {
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0.1875em 0.1875em 0.5em / 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #09313d, inset 0 1px 1px #c0edf3;
    background: #e12726;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -0.375em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 0.125em rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
    width: 2.25em;
    height: 2.25em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 .125em .125em #3b4547;
    background: $brandbasic;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% .125em, .125em 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 115% 115%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 1px #516570);
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 0.125em rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
    width: 2.25em;
    height: 2.25em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 .125em .125em #3b4547;
    background: radial-gradient(#777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 70%) 50% 50%, radial-gradient(#777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 70%) 50% 50%, radial-gradient(at 50% 0 at 50% 0, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 50% 0, radial-gradient(at 50% 100% at 50% 100%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 50% 100%, radial-gradient(at 0 50% at 0 50%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 0 50%, radial-gradient(at 100% 50% at 100% 50%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 100% 50%, radial-gradient(rgba(59, 69, 71, 0) 50%, #3b4547 71%) 50% -0.25em #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% .125em, .125em 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 115% 115%;
}
input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 0.125em rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
    width: 2.25em;
    height: 2.25em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 .125em .125em #3b4547;
    background: radial-gradient(#777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 70%) 50% 50%, radial-gradient(#777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 70%) 50% 50%, radial-gradient(at 50% 0 at 50% 0, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 50% 0, radial-gradient(at 50% 100% at 50% 100%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 50% 100%, radial-gradient(at 0 50% at 0 50%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 0 50%, radial-gradient(at 100% 50% at 100% 50%, #777777, rgba(119, 119, 119, 0) 71%) 100% 50%, radial-gradient(rgba(59, 69, 71, 0) 50%, #3b4547 71%) 50% -0.25em #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% .125em, .125em 100%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 50%, 115% 115%;
}
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track:before, .js input[type='range'] /deep/ #track:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.25em;
    left: 0.25em;
    width: 0em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0.1875em 0.1875em 0.5em / 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px #09313d, inset 0 1px 1px #c0edf3;
    background: #e12726;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    content:'';
}
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:before, .js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:after, .js input[type='range'] /deep/ #thumb:before, .js input[type='range'] /deep/ #thumb:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    color: #ebeef3;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(211, 23, 22, 0.5);
}
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:before, .js input[type='range'] /deep/ #thumb:before {
    width: 4em;
    height: 2.25em;
    border-radius: 0.125em;
    transform: translate(-50%, -0.5em);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #d1e4f9;
    background: #212121;
    clip-path: polygon(2.375em 1.875em, 2em 2.25em, 1.625em 1.875em, 0.125em 1.875em, 0.07716em 1.86548em, 0.03661em 1.83839em, 0.00952em 1.79784em, 0em 1.75em, 0em 0.125em, 0.00952em 0.07716em, 0.03661em 0.03661em, 0.07716em 0.00952em, 0.125em 0em, 3.875em 0em, 3.92284em 0.00952em, 3.96339em 0.03661em, 3.99048em 0.07716em, 4em 0.125em, 4em 1.75em, 3.99048em 1.79784em, 3.96339em 1.83839em, 3.92284em 1.86548em, 3.875em 1.875em);
    font: 2em/1.40625em trebuchet ms, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    content:"0%";
}
.js input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb:after, .js input[type='range'] /deep/ #thumb:after {
    width: 9.6em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -2.75em);
    box-shadow: 0 2.25em 0.625em -0.5em rgba(55, 84, 92, 0.75);
    font: 0.75em trebuchet ms, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap;
    content:"Making an enquiry";
}
input[type='range']:focus {
    outline: none;
    opacity: .99;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <input type='range' id="commitmentdesktop" class="form-control" name="commitmentdesktop" value='0' step="20">
        <select id="commitmentmobile" name="commitmentmobile" class="form-control smaller-select">
            <option>&nbsp;</option>
            <!-- NOTE: These are now generated in JavaScript.
            <option value="5">I'm ready to Start</option>
            <option value="4">I want to do this</option>
            <option value="3">I'm very interested</option>
            <option value="2">I want to know more</option>
            <option value="1">I'm not sure this is right for me</option>
            <option value="0">Just making an enquiry</option>
            -->
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! You are incredible to have done that for me- thank you! Just to clarify/understand - you've placed the corresponding messages/values within an array, then used a for loop to access that array to populate the options box (and because the range value is linked it's updated also). The first event listener calling the updateSlider() function and the second calls the updateSlider() function after the 'option' input changes. And the updateSlider() function has been updated to 'Fixed the scale logic' as you have said (which I get but don't understand yet - I'll get there). Am I reading it right?

Comment: Yeah, since you know the ***step*** and the ***index***, you can compute the value by ***multiplying*** them together. Item at index `3` is *"Very Interested"*. To get the percentage value all we do is multiply it's position in the `<SELECT>` box by the step. We get the value `60`, which is the corresponding value in the `<INPUT type="range">`.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Thank you once again - especially for helping out a beginner :-) Have a great day!